# How to group consecutive rows having same event and find average?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
Value <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
Event <- c(1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2)

group <- data.frame(pt=Value, Event=Event)
```

I have data like above and I would like to group events in a way that would result into following.

```
Event Value
1     2.5
2     4
1     12.5
2     4
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can create a grouping variable with `rleid` from `data.table`, use that to get the `mean` of 'pt' as well as return the `first` value of 'Event'

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
group %>%
    group_by(grp = rleid(Event)) %>% 
    summarise(Event = first(Event), Value = mean(pt)) %>%
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Event Value
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1   2.5
#2     2   4  
#3     1  12.5
#4     2   4
```

---

Or using `tapply/rle` in `base R`

```
with(group, tapply(pt, with(rle(Event),
     rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = mean))
#    1    2    3    4 
#  2.5  4.0 12.5  4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `cumsum`:

```
dfs %>% 
mutate(gr = cumsum(Event != lag(Event, default = 0))) %>% 
group_by(gr, Event) %>% summarise(mean_Value = mean(Value)) %>% 
ungroup()
```